The value is not stored in the database
I'm now making a code in HTML that saves the value in the database when you type it in input.
However, if you enter a value in the input and press the button, the value should be stored in the users table in the user.db file, but it does not work.
I made the server Glitch and I saved the HTML file on my computer.
First of all, the code in server.js is this (saved to Glitch and running)
const express = require('express');
const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

// SQLite 데이터베이스 연결
const db = new sqlite3.Database('user.db');

// POST 요청을 처리하는 미들웨어 설정
app.use(express.json());

// 클라이언트로부터의 POST 요청 처리
app.post('/register', (req, res) => {
    const { nickname, password, email } = req.body;

    // 데이터베이스에 데이터 삽입
    db.run(`INSERT INTO users(username, email, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?)`, [nickname, email, password], function (err) {
        if (err) {
            return console.error('Error inserting data into database:', err.message);
        }
        // 데이터베이스에 성공적으로 삽입된 경우
        console.log(`A row has been inserted with rowid ${this.lastID}`);
        res.json({ message: 'Data inserted successfully' });
    });
});

// 서버 시작
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on http://localhost:${port}`);
});


And client.js and index.html.
client.js
function sendData() {
    const nickname = document.getElementById('nickname').value;
    const password = document.getElementById('password').value;
    const email = document.getElementById('email').value;

    // 데이터를 객체로 만들어 JSON 형식으로 변환
    const data = {
        nickname: nickname,
        password: password,
        email: email
    };

    // 서버에 POST 요청을 보냄
    fetch('https://carnelian-abalone-periwinkle.glitch.me/register', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
    })
    .then(response => {
        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
        }
        return response.json();
    })
    .then(data => {
        console.log('Server response:', data);
        // 여기서 필요한 추가 작업을 수행할 수 있습니다.
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error('Error sending data to server:', error);
    });
}

index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>회원가입</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input id="nickname" placeholder="닉네임">
        <input id="password" placeholder="비밀번호" type="password">
        <input id="email" placeholder="이메일">
        <button onclick="sendData()">가입</button>

        <script src="client.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>


However, even if you enter a value on the site and press the button, the value is not saved in user.db.
I think Glitch and my computer are connected, but I can't save the value.
What is the reason?
Value cannot be added to the database.

You need to add the "name" attribute to each input field. Without this attribute, the data won't be submitted
Example:
<input id="nickname" name="nickname" placeholder="닉네임">
<input id="password" name="password" placeholder="비밀번호" type="password">
<input id="email" name"email" placeholder="이메일">

